# DPLYR Mutate function to "transmute"?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've just started picking up R a few weeks ago. I'm having some problems trying to transmute (if this is the right R term?) the gender row to column.

```
    > brfss %>%
    +     filter(hours1 >=1,hours1 <=24) %>%
    +     group_by(hours1, gender) %>%
    +     summarise(count = n())
    # A tibble: 48 x 3
    # Groups:   hours1 [?]
       hours1   gender count
          <int> <fctr> <int>
     1        1   Male    96
     2        1 Female   132
     3        2   Male   464
     4        2 Female   612
     5        3   Male  1433
     6        3 Female  2063
     7        4   Male  5749
     8        4 Female  8512
     9        5   Male 13231
    10        5 Female 20205

    # ... with 38 more rows
```

I want to display the column as:

```
    hours1   Male  Female count
```

basically transmuting the whole Male/Female to column instead of rows. Can someone give me some pointers? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R how to create pivot table-like data frame while 3 variables are involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597542/r-how-to-create-pivot-table-like-data-frame-while-3-variables-are-involved)

Comment: Does ^^ answer your q @junha082?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've already checked that post, its not really to do with obtaining a mean of a value  (I would probably use transmute/summarise for those), rather transmuting the whole gender from row to column. But let me google on Dcast from reshape2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

brfss2013 %>% 
  select(hours1 = sleptim1, gender = sex) %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(hours1, gender) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  spread(key = gender, value = count)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, the second one is what I'm trying to achieve. just installed the tidyr package.
When I run it it says:
        Error in brfss %>% spread(key = gender, value = count) : 
  could not find function "%>%"

additionally, I have included count = n() in my previous code, how does the count here calculate that?

Comment: source of the data is from the 2013 BRFSS survey: https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_384b2d9eda4b29131fb681b243a7767d_brfss2013.RData?Expires=1508112000&Signature=d3igdAz-A-h0dibkyU-oOTOweO~I9OsksFOLxKxEgMnQRFJWxENJJG6gYFsbhQVw-56mne4Tjo6NMN3biO61Ba2BAWR4HOPX5MHiSkzq92ph~QIFZaHg7aJOoK56kNQVqm7SRhBL4kr7jBvLWiAUk7ilulJZq7ejIk2~tm60gnk_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A

Comment: I'm using data from sleptim1, sex to try to populate out the sleptim1, male, female, count/total (which I can mutate later on to sum both male and female) @jsb

Comment: Is `sleptim1` what you call `hours1`?

Comment: Updated my answer now.

Comment: that's exactly what i'm looking for! learned a few things along the way, thanks!

Comment: If you find the answer satisfactory, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score -4):

try this..
brfss %>% 
  spread(key = gender, value = gender) %>% 
  select(hours1, Male, Female, count)